# Why we are unable to decrypt the data in java that is encrypted in python using RSA Encryption using ECB/PKCS1

Tags: java, python, encryption, cryptography, padding

Here is the code for encrypting the data in python

```py
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from base64 import b64decode
import base64


mode = AES.MODE_CBC
key_bytes="HTj9bAAAMg9XxK6uLs4JGg==" # random 128 bit key generated 
iv_bytes = "SECRETKEY"
cipher = AES.new(key_bytes, mode, iv_bytes)


def pad(text):
byteNum = len(text)
packingLength = 8 - byteNum % 8
appendage = chr(packingLength) * packingLength
data=text + appendage
return data


plain_text="some text to encrypt"
data = pad(plain_text)
encrypted_bytes = cipher.encrypt(data)
encrypted_string = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(encrypted_bytes)
encrytid = open("encryptid.txt",'w')      #writting encrypted data for ref
encrytid.write(encrypted_string)
encrytid.close()
keys = b64decode('HTj9bAAAMg9XxK6uLs4JGg==')
key = (open('public.pem', 'rb').read())   #reading public.pem data
rsakey = RSA.importKey(key)
rsakey = PKCS1_OAEP.new(rsakey)
encrypted = rsakey.encrypt(keys)
                        #print ("enc: ", encrypted)
encrypt_aes = base64.b64encode(encrypted)
```

and here is the java code use to decrypt above output:

when we try to decrypt the data using java we are getting bellow error:

ERROR

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
 at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:363)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2121)
```

can some one suggest the possible solution to resolve the issue...

Comment: Random thought: In your python code you say AES but the java exception is RSA?

Comment: Your java code is incomplete. There is no way for us to understand your error without the complete code.

Comment: sorry my bad updating the code with RSA code..

Comment: This is still incomplete. The python code imports RSA, but never uses it. The Java code has no *public static void main* function.

Comment: your code is incomplete, but i think (according to error text) you uses wrong algorithm/mode/padding in decription

Comment: @ mikeazo can you please check once ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using OAEP for encryption in Python and PKCS#1 padding for decryption in Java. Those two are different RSA encryption schemes, even if they are both present in the PKCS#1 v2.1 and 2.2 standards. You should use OAEP (using SHA-1 as it is the default) in Java as well. It should be present the Oracle JRE.

Comment: Thanks for the information,
Actually java code is fixed and python code can be changed,,, can you please guide us how to fix the issue... 
Thanks in advance ...

Comment: once again thanks for the hint it worked and now it's giving error in other part....

javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:966)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:824)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:436)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2121)

Comment: Currently it is not possible for me to test your code. Why not create a minimal OAEP only test, where you print out the output of encrypt and input for decrypt in hex? I see one URL safe encoder and one that is not; if the input is invalid, then you will get these kind of failures.

Comment: @ Maarten Bodewes: encryption is done using PKCS1_v1_5.new Updated my code.. and now it's working but coming to pkcs5 padding it's getting error and one more thing changed the urlsafe also....

Comment: @ Maarten Bodewes: thanks buddy the issue got fixed and now we are able to encrypt the data using python and decrypt the data using java with out any issues... 

thanks for every thing and your time....

Answer (score 0):

as we fixed the key and iv values we got the error and then we generated them using random functions.
then one more thing the key and iv are in two different formats that we are not supposed to pass.. I got the error while decrypting the data in java...
finally fixed the issues with required steps....